# Unicorn & Rails & Supervisor + Capistrano deploys: Stopping and starting unicorn gracefully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn, restart

This caused me no end of pain due to the unexpected unicorn requirements, so I thought I'd leave my solution here for anyone else:

I'm running
- Ruby 2.3.1
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Unicorn 5.3.0
- Supervisor

The main issue I had was with the graceful restart.  I was sending the following to the supervisor process:

```
supervisorctl signal USR2 unicorn
```

Unicorn would process the signal, and gracefully restart. However - every so often, developers would complain that their code hadn't loaded, and a little more infrequently, the entire restart process would fail.

What was happening was that Unicorn when signalled was not honouring the working_directory, and was instead attempting to reload from the previous symlink.  This was despite the working directory in the unicorn config being set to /path/to/app/current rather than the underlying /path/to/release/directory.

Unicorn would restart the workers from the previous deployed application, and when the initial release directory was purged from system (i.e. capistrano being set to keep X releases), the process would fail, because the release directory unicorn had been initially started in would have been removed from the system.

The key is to add the following in the unicorn.conf.rb file:

```
Unicorn::HttpServer::START_CTX[:cwd] = "/path/to/current"
Unicorn::HttpServer::START_CTX[0] = "/path/to/your/unicorn-rails/binary"
```

And to also explicitly define the bundle gemfile path (as unicorn on load was setting this to the initial release directory, and again ignoring the /path/to/current).

```
before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "/path/to/current/Gemfile"
end
```

I've posted my entire configuration below:

```
# Unicorn supervisor config
[program:unicorn]
command=/bin/start_unicorn.sh 
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/program_supervise_unicorn.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/program_supervise_unicorn.error
priority=100
user=web_user
directory=/srv/applications/ewok/current
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=QUIT


#Unicorn start script (start_unicorn.sh)
!/bin/bash
source /etc/profile
cd /srv/applications/ewok/current
exec bundle exec unicornherder -u unicorn_rails -p 
/srv/applications/ewok/shared/pids/unicorn.pid -- -c config/unicorn.conf.rb -E $RAILS_ENV
exit 0 


# My unicorn.conf.rb
APP_PATH = "/srv/applications/ewok/current"
SHARED_PATH = "/srv/applications/ewok/shared"

Unicorn::HttpServer::START_CTX[:cwd] = APP_PATH
Unicorn::HttpServer::START_CTX[0] = "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ewok/bin/unicorn_rails"

worker_processes 3
working_directory APP_PATH
listen "unix:#{SHARED_PATH}/pids/.unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64
listen 8080, :tcp_nopush => true
timeout 30
pid "#{SHARED_PATH}/pids/unicorn.pid"
old_pid ="#{SHARED_PATH}/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"
stderr_path "#{SHARED_PATH}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{SHARED_PATH}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
preload_app true

GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

#check_client_connection false
run_once = true

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{APP_PATH}/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and 
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  run_once = false if run_once # prevent from firing again

  # Before forking, kill the master process that belongs to the .oldbin 
PID.
  # This enables 0 downtime deploys.
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
  begin
    Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
  rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    # someone else did our job for us
  end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Hope this helps somebody, as I was about to start considering monkey patching unicorn itself before I fixed it.

Comment: It's best to place the answer not as part of the question but on its own below.